# XElement multiple root elements

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have below XML format to Create by XElement class

[image: XML Source]

In Which you can see I have two parent node Service and Catalog. Now when I read from source below is code snippet

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("Catalog", new XElement("Service"));//Create a root Element 

foreach (....)// Logic for multiple product element 

XElement productElement = new XElement("Product", new XAttribute("name", Obj.Product));//Read the Product
XElement variantElement = new XElement("Variant", new XAttribute("name",Obj.Variant));//Read variant
XElement skuElement = new XElement("SKU", new XAttribute("name", Obj.SKU));//Read SKU

productElement.Add(variantElement, skuElement);//Add varaint and skuvariant to product
rootElement.Add(productElement);//Add product to root element
```

But the Output is not expected,below is the output

[image]

You can see the second parent node appears as closure at the beginning. 

  
I know this line is creating the issue

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("Catalog", new XElement("Service"));
```

but I need two root elements? What is the solution? How can i create?

Please help.

Comment: The only root element is Catalog. XML documents may *not* contain multiple root elements. Also, please paste the XML and output in the question itself as code (not as an image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Service` element will always be empty because you never actually add anything to it, you just create it. You add your products to the `Catalog` element instead of adding them to the `Service` element.

Also, calling these "roots" isn't correct terminology as a valid XML document can only have one root (so in this case the only root element is `Catalog`).

Here's the code:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string VariantName { get; set; }

        public string SKU { get; set; }
    }

    private static void CreateDoc(List<Product> list)
    {
        XElement serviceElement = new XElement("Service");
        XElement rootElement = new XElement("Catalog", serviceElement);//Create a root Element 

        // Obviously include the foreach loop
        foreach (Product product in list)
        {
            // Obviously replace these hardcoded string with your actual object values
            XElement productElement = new XElement("Product", new XAttribute("name", product.ProductName));//Read the Product
            XElement variantElement = new XElement("Variant", new XAttribute("name", product.VariantName));//Read variant
            XElement skuElement = new XElement("SKU", new XAttribute("name", product.SKU));//Read SKU

            productElement.Add(variantElement, skuElement);//Add varaint and skuvariant to product

            // Add product to the Service element, NOT to the root. The root is Catalog.
            serviceElement.Add(productElement);
        }

        rootElement.Save("XmlFile.xml");
    }
```

The main changes are

```
// Store the Service element is a variable so we can add stuff to it
XElement serviceElement = new XElement("Service");

// ...

// Add to the Service element instead of to Catalog
serviceElement.Add(productElement);
```

I call it like this:

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { ProductName = "SomeName", SKU = "SomeSKU", VariantName = "VariantA" },
            new Product { ProductName = "AnotherProduct", SKU = "AnotherSKU", VariantName = "VariantB" },
            new Product { ProductName = "ProductC", SKU = "SKUc", VariantName = "VariantC" }
        };

        CreateDoc(list);
```

Here's the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Catalog is the root element for this document -->
<Catalog>
  <!-- Service is NOT a root element, even though it's the only child of Catalog -->
  <Service>
    <!-- Each Service element can have an arbitrary number of Product elements -->
    <Product name="SomeName">
      <Variant name="VariantA" />
      <SKU name="SomeSKU" />
    </Product>
    <Product name="AnotherProduct">
      <Variant name="VariantB" />
      <SKU name="AnotherSKU" />
    </Product>
    <Product name="ProductC">
      <Variant name="VariantC" />
      <SKU name="SKUc" />
    </Product>
  </Service>
</Catalog>
```

Another clarification - in this case `Service` is *not* a root element (even though it's the only child of `Catalog` in this case).

Comment: Thanks EJoshuaS! The above code will add service element for each of the product element but my requirement is to have as parent element i.e <Catalog> <Service>.....</Service></Catalog> ,i know the well formed XML will have only root element but i need two here...let me know any possibilities or any solution?..thanks troy

Comment: @Troy I edited to make it a little clearer - there can be an arbitrary number of products for each service.